# why refresh token does not work with bigquery API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I use bigquery API, I put refresk token because the access_token is short-lived only around 1h (3600s) but my problem is it doesn't work
The api's  response is always "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials", it means that bigquery doesn't accept the token.
have anyone an idea about it? I have to use the refresh token to avoid this short-lived token.
Or is there impossible to use refresh token with API bigquery?
thank you so much for your replies

Answer (score 2):

You always need to use `access_token`, the refresh_token is used to renew the access_token. You should not confuse these. It's not a replacement.

To properly understand how OAuth2.0 works read this:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2